# Can putty launch external program upon receiving an escaped character sequence?

Tags: ssh, putty, openssh

In **xterm** (*inheritance of ansi and vt100 terminfos*) are some escape sequences which can control somethings in the client emulator, and the `putty.exe` client understands some of these sequences, like:

- *Passthrough* printer (slave printer)
- Changing the window size, zooming, ...
- Changing the window title
- *Answerback*
- Maybe others.

Are there ways to tell `putty.exe` to launch an arbitrary (external) program ? (Previously configured, of course)

**USE CASES:** Exchanging data from the server to the local computer

Case 1) A remote application (TUI - curses based) could send data to the slave printer, which would be sent to a "file printer", and when it's over, a local application would be run to consume the data received in the "file printer". Some convention could be used to format the file name, to all these match and work in sync.

Case 2) A remote application could save the data in the server, and ask putty.exe to launch an local script to get the remote file, and so launch a local program to consume it.

And a lot of others use cases.

Comment: Did you solve your issue? if so, I would like to know how

Comment: @hmontoliu No. I didn't. I miss this feature yet. we

Comment: I've been able to launch client-side programs by using Aljex putty's fork. https://github.com/aljex/aljex-client/blob/master/readme.txt HTH

Comment: Assuming you're running putty on a windows client, you could use AutoHotKey to "watch" the putty window for certain text. https://autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=25103

Comment: @AaronCicali Nice approach. However, it seems to need a visible text, rather than an "escaped" sequence of characters (so an invisible and binary string)